# aframe ar.js "clicks" fuera del area del marcador

Tags: javascript, html, ar.js

¿Alguien sabe cómo activar el clic incluso cuando está "fuera" del marcador?
Tengo 3 cubos con 3 enlaces diferentes, pero solo funciona el que se encuentra "dentro" de los límites físicos del marcador, los que están afuera no se activan.
Intente cambiar el atributo "tamaño" en "a-marker", pero nada cambia.
[image: Sólo en el cubo del centro funciona el "click"]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mejor para eso es, que no pongas el evento onclick en el boton, mejor crea un div y dentro pon el boton, y le das el evento onclick al div

```
<div onclick="myFunction()" style="border:2px solid black; width:80px; height:80px;">
  <button>boton</button>
</div>
<script>
  function myFunction(){
    alert("test")
  }
</script>
```

De esta manera puedes ajustar el tamaño que quieras al div, y el evento on click funcionara dentro de esa area